# Powershell Script to Bulk Update Active Directory Pagre field from a CSV not working

Tags: powershell, active-directory, import-csv

So I've got a CSV File with the following format to bulk edit the Pager field in active directory and I can't seem to figure out why it's erroring out.

```
SamAccountName Pager
User1,85098838
User2,85939379
User3,85738299
```

**Here's the script:**

```
# Import the Active Directory module
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

# Define the path to the CSV file
$csvFilePath = "C:\pager.csv"

# Read the CSV file
$users = Import-Csv $csvFilePath

# Loop through each user in the CSV and update the Pager field
foreach ($user in $users) {
    $samAccountName = $user.SamAccountName
    $pagerValue = $user.Pager

    # Get the user object from Active Directory
    $userObj = Get-ADUser -Filter {SamAccountName -eq $samAccountName}

    if ($userObj) {
        # Update the Pager field
        Set-ADUser -Identity $userObj -Pager $pagerValue

        Write-Host "Updated Pager for user $samAccountName with value: $pagerValue"
    } else {
        Write-Host "User $samAccountName not found in Active Directory."
    }
}
```

**And here's the error I get:**

```
Get-ADUser : Variable: 'samAccountName' found in expression: $samAccountName is not defined.
At line:9 char:16
+ ...    $userObj = Get-ADUser -Filter {SamAccountName -eq $samAccountName}
+                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ADUser], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser
 
User  not found in Active Directory.
```

Any ideas on what I'm missing?

I was expecting it to work and update the AD field pager

Comment: Looks like your csv file does not have a column `SamAccountName` or in some cases there is no value entered there. Is your csv **comma** delimited or does it use a different field separator character? `Filter` should actually be a string, not a scriptblock: `-Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$samAccountName'"`

Comment: You're missing a `,` between `SamAccountName` and `Pager` in the CSV file